# como hacer un boton responsive con bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy practicando haciendo una pag que sea responsive con bootstrap4, el problema lo tengo en un carousel, este tiene un boton el cual es btn-lg, que se ve bien en grande pero en pantallas pequeñas (xs) se ve demasiado grande, despues de intentar varias cosas lo solucione con css colocandole un width y height en una `@media` para pantallas pequeñas, me preguntaba si no hay una forma mas "elegante" de hacerlo con bootstrap ( algo como class="btn-sm-lg btn-sm" )

Esta es la porcion de css para el boton

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .botonpequeno{
        width: 7rem;
        height: 2.1rem;
        font-size: 70%;
    }
```

Y esta es la porcion del html del carousel ( los botones estan dentro de los "carousel-item" luego dentro de "carousel-caption" y en la "p" tag )

```html
<main role="main">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="static/imgs/carousel4.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carouselimg" alt="imposible cargar imagen de fondo">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1 class="text-dark display-1">Example headline.</h1>
                        <p class="text-dark lead carousel-lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary botonpequeno" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="static/imgs/carousel2.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carouselimg" alt="imposible cargar imagen de fondo">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1 class="text-dark display-1">Another example headline.</h1>
                        <p class="text-dark lead carousel-lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary botonpequeno" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="static/imgs/carousel3.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carouselimg" alt="imposible cargar imagen de fondo">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1 class="text-dark display-1">One more for good measure.</h1>
                        <p class="text-dark lead carousel-lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary botonpequeno" href="#" role="button">Gallery</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="static/imgs/carousel5.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carouselimg" alt="imposible cargar imagen de fondo">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1 class="text-dark display-1">One more for good measure.</h1>
                        <p class="text-dark lead carousel-lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary botonpequeno" href="#" role="button">Gallery</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Esa no es la forma correcta de trabajar con carousel en Bootstrap, no debes usar `<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">`, las clases correctas son: `"carousel-control-next"` y `"carousel-control-prev"`. Estas clases vienen con íconos svg que se adaptan automáticamente según el dispositivo, están especificados dentro de un `<span>`.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es incluir botones pero más pequeños, simplemente usa la clase `btn-sm` después de la clase `btn`.